# Map of Map in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

Why is this not working:

```
CREATE TABLE bwlists (uuid uuid PRIMARY KEY, bwl map<ascii, bw map<ascii, ascii>>);
```

I got:

> Bad Request: line 1:79 no viable alternative at input '>'

Comment: Not certain on this, but it seems like it should be: `bwl map<ascii>, bw map<ascii, ascii>`

Comment: This also not working.

Comment: It isn't supported in Cassandra.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE bwlists (
  uuid uuid PRIMARY KEY, 
  bwl map<ascii, bw map<ascii, ascii>>);

Bad Request: line 1:79 no viable alternative at input '>'
```

Your first problem, is that you are trying to name the map `bw` within the `bwl` map.  That's not going to work, as CQL is not expecting to find an identifier (instead of a type).  Your syntax can then be adjusted to this:

```
CREATE TABLE bwlists (
  uuid uuid PRIMARY KEY, 
  bwl map<ascii, map<ascii, ascii>>);
```

But that still doesn't work.  Running this `CREATE` statement yields this message:

```
<ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query]
  message="map type cannot contain another collection">
```

Currently, Cassandra/CQL does not permit creating a "map of a map."

Also, it's not a good idea to use reserved words as column names, even if Cassandra lets you do it.  I'd rename `uuid` to something more context-specific to your application.